# Using JSP tags in grails

Tags: grails, taglib

I'm still new to grails and i kind of stuck in a problem where i can't use the Jsp tags that i put in the /WEB-INF/tags

if i create a tag file called text.tag and put in it the normal HTML input text tag
 and i go to the GSP and make the taglib 
 < %@ taglib prefix="myTags" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags"%>
then trying to call it by 
< myTags:text/>
it gives me nothing.. in fact if i checked the html source i find < mytags:text/>
is there special way for that cause i need that in more sophisticated tags.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend writing the tags as grails tags

http://grails.org/Dynamic%20Tag%20Libraries

those tags are easier to write, but the answer to your original question is also documented at the link above

Comment: the link you have put sir is not answering my question it's state of how to use GSP tags in the jsp.. while what i need is the opposite .. cause i have a tag to control the famous displayTag and i can't use it in grails for some reason.. so is that have any solution

Comment: my apologies.... take a look at this test project that was included in the JIRA for grails. I has customs tags and the code works.

http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-4571

Comment: it seems that i'm just having a low level IQ :D but i can't find the solution in this :-S..

Comment: if you download the associated project, and look at the code, you will see there is a custom tag included in the project. Running the project  will demonstrate the functioning custom tag in a grails project.

Comment: will .. if it's ok with you i'd like to have direct contact with you to share those infos cause it seems that i'm suck at this :D

my contacts is
emadhegab@hotmail.com
emadhegab@gmail.com
emadhegab274@yahoo.com
emadhegab   for skype
wait for your answer sir :)